# how to restrict pagination to certain pages in Django

Tags: django, pagination

I am a newbie in django following this example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyElWFn3XT4)  ... everything seems to be working but the problem is with the pagination, as it is configured in base page and it is reflected on all the pages ... how can i restrict the pagination to certain pages ...

Code

```
<ul class="pagination">

                <li class="page-item {% if not prev_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">
                    
                  <a class="page-link" href="{{ prev_page_url }}" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
                </li>

               {% for n in page.paginator.page_range %}
                   {% if page.number == n %}
                        <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                           <a class="page-link" href=="?page={{n}}">{{n}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                   {% elif n > page.number|add:-3 and n < page.number|add:3  %}
                        <li class="page_item">
                          <a class="page-link" href ="?page={{n}}">{{n}}</a>
                       </li>
                   {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

                <li class="page-item {% if not next_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">
                  <a class="page-link" href="{{next_page_url}}">Next</a>
                </li>

              </ul>
```

[image: Proper Pagination dispalyed here]

but on this page or 2 other pages i don't want pagination to be displayed ( i.e. Next and Previous button displayed).

[image: Post page]
[image: unwanted pagintion]

Can some please help me on this ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if pagination is enabled to determine if you want to show your buttons

```
{%if page.paginator %}
    <ul class="pagination">

            <li class="page-item {% if not prev_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">
                
              <a class="page-link" href="{{ prev_page_url }}" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Previous</a>
            </li>

           {% for n in page.paginator.page_range %}
               {% if page.number == n %}
                    <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                       <a class="page-link" href=="?page={{n}}">{{n}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
               {% elif n > page.number|add:-3 and n < page.number|add:3  %}
                    <li class="page_item">
                      <a class="page-link" href ="?page={{n}}">{{n}}</a>
                   </li>
               {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            <li class="page-item {% if not next_page_url %} disabled {% endif %} ">
              <a class="page-link" href="{{next_page_url}}">Next</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, I was thinking in another to get the pagination count and if it is greater than 1, then display